# The partitions of Windows is not seen in Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I have an windows 10 system with 1 TB HDD, today I dual boot it with ubuntu 18.04, in the disk section the picture is like this,

[image]

But there is no sign of these partitions, like this,
[image]

When I click on Windows network the message is this,

[image]

Now please give me some solution.

Comment: Did you turn off Windows fast start up? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Is drive in AHCI mode in UEFI settings? Not RAID, nor IDE?

Comment: Turn of Windows fast-start,  in windows powershell or commandline type `powercfg.exe -h off`. I'm not sure, it's a long time I need this, but I think it is also necessary to disable hibernation.

Answer (score 0):

The partition /sda7 is not formatted; your file manager can only view and interact with partitions which are formatted for usability. Those are
/sda1 (NTFS, recovery partition, hidden)
/sda2 (FAT), and
/sda11 (Ext4, Linux).